# How can I remove some characters from a C# string?

Tags: c#

I have the string:

```
http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3
```

The number 96 could be anything from 75 to 125.

Is there a simple way that I could remove this number to get:

```
http://127.0.0.1/Cambia3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

convert to a URI and then pull out the information you are interested in

```
var ip= new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3");
var withoutPort = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", ip.Scheme, ip.Host, ip.PathAndQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable - you can't change them - but you can create new one from pieces of old one.

In your case do not use string manipulation - Uri and UriBuilder classes should be used when changing Urls.

Sample:

```
var builder=new UriBuilder("http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3");
builder.Port = 80;
Console.WriteLine(builder.Uri.AbsoluteUri);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the below code

```
string str = "http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3";
int index1 = str.IndexOf(':', 7);
int index2 = str.IndexOf('/', 7);

str.Remove(index1, index2 - index1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can try something on these lines

```
UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder("http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3");
uri.Port =-1;            
string portlessurl = uri.Uri.AbsoluteUri; // Output -- http://127.0.0.1/Cambia3
```

Answer (score 0):

For simply removing it would always use this:

```
string ip = "http://127.0.0.1:96/Cambia3";
ip = ip.Replace(":96", string.Empty);
```

If needed later you can always reuse this to replace the port.